# Android Google Play Services returning old GPS data

Tags: android, service, gps, location

I’m having some issue with the GPS position provided by the Google Play Services and something about the connection with it. Here where I work, we have an app that tracks the position of taxis around our city. A very few users reported that sometimes their position gets stuck, and the map view, it shows the position that is stuck (and where he isn't anymore). The only way to fix it in their device was to clear the cache open the app.

When it was implemented, we followed the official tutorial to obtain the current location of the device. After obtaining the position, we display it on the map and send the location coordinates to our backend, that logs the position of the user device. To analyze the bug, we tried some fixes, followed other implementations approaches, and even set to log to the backend the “age” of the data (current time - time that was obtained the position). None of the approaches fixed the issue, but the “age” did gave us a hint: While the position kept the same, their age kept growing. In other words, the device was sending the same gps data to the backend. By debugging it, we found out that the Google Play Services was returning an old data, instead of a new one.

We did found a workaround, that is restarting the connection with the Google Play Services in the device after 1 minute stuck. That way, it forces the Google Play Services to reconnect and kinda “solved” the stuck position, but again, it isn’t a permanent fix. It works, but is ugly.

It fells like the connection to the play services ends, but there is no feedback about it, or even why did it ended in the first place. While researching about it, we couldn't find any relation to device model, or a specific version.

Since the bug, we were using the ADT in Eclipse, and the the Google Play Services Library version 7327000.
Now, we are with Android Studio and using the Play Services:7.5.0, and still with it.

Does anyone here known what might be causing it and, hopefully, a solution?

Thanks in advance,

Vinícius Henriques

Comment: So you're never actually registering for location updates? Just reading the last location?

Comment: As I said, I've followed tutorials about the GPS. The whole proccess happens and works, from the registering to the reconnection callback. The location update works. It's just that, out of the nowhere, some users start sending the old location, instead of the current one.